# Reaching and Pulling Environment Variables in TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

Currently my Office is running a AHK script to pull environment variables. These Env Variables are then used as a specific outputted data when closing tickets as my Office has a ticket closing environment. This works for the time being however I am looking into automating this process and starting off just trying to auto close the tickets when a specific key is pressed. I have been able to perform this task but I have to basically have static variables in the TamperMonkey script for each user. Everyone using this ticket site has the specific environment variables already due to the AHK script and want to try and implement this into the Tampermonkey script without having to change the site completely.

I have locally hosted the site and used Node to do this and I am successful in doing this but it does not work on the Tampermonkey route. I have been using process.env.ENV_VARIABLE on the node side but I am trying to refrain from completely implementing this on the site itself. I have added some basic variable examples in a Autohotkey Script already being used.

```
GetGreeting() {
    global greeting
    return greeting
}

GetSalutation() {
    global salutation
    return salutation
}

GetUserName() {
    Envget, e_Ticketname, Ticketuser
    return e_Ticketname
}
```

When a specific Key is pressed it should write the specific message and include said specific Env Variables. Currently I don't think I have it where Tampermonkey can actually understand the Environment Variables as it keeps giving a undefined error. Any Ideas.

Comment: Where are these environment variables? You also mention AHK - how is that supposed to interact with TamperMonkey? TM runs in the browser, while AHK outside of it. From what I gather, you want to somehow bridge the two but I'm not sure how you want that to happen and how much (if any) control you have over the AHK script as well as how much (if any) control you have over those environment variables on the site.

Comment: OK, so in that case where are the environment variables defined? The OS? Because I don't think you have access to those in a browser.

Comment: The Office is currently using AHK. I am trying to get rid of that completely as it is just a copy/paste solution. In the AHK there are predefined  strings that are outputted when lets say F6 was pressed you would get a preset message placed into a message box. Mantis Bug tracker is being used as a base ticket site. Don't need any control over the environment variables other than taking the output and setting it as a variable in the Tampermonkey script. The Environment Variables are just on the users local machine in the registry. However you can use the dotenv module to use these variables.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to edit it and Didnt get a chance to fix it.

Comment: Ideally on my locally hosted version of the ticket site as a test I have implemented this Node.js module where I have a .env file in the site file tree that the JS files read for their variables https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv. I don't think there is any way to do it in Tampermonkey and I cant seem to find anyone with an answer. If not my thinking will have to change on implementing it for a few people here. I just didn't want to implement this big change for 4 people.  No worries if there isnt a way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So upon further investigation it does not appear to be a way to interact with the OS inside the browser. I will be looking into another way to do what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access and run local files as JavaScript code in Tampermonkey using `\\ @require`

So if you're able to have a local file with the content in this format:

```
variables = {
    var1: "hello there"  
}
```

Then in the script, add this line and add the path to the file.

```
// @require     file://Path\to\file
```

Since all the file has is an assignment to a variable, then you can access that in the script

```
console.log(variables.var1) // logs "hello there"
```

For this you need to give the extension access to file URLs:

- go to `chrome://extensions`
- Tampermonkey > Details
- Allow access to file URLs

You'll still need a way to generate the file in that format in the user machine though, either manually, or some code running locally.

A way to generate the file, could be using Node locally, but if you're running that locally, at that point another way to get local data is to serve it using a simple http server (like Node server), then you could make a request from Tampermonkey using `fetch` or `GM_xmlhttpRequest`

---

As a side note, a hack I use to run code locally triggered with Tampermonkey, is to use the [localexplorer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl). The extension allows you to open files and folder from the browser using "localexplorer://" urls, so then with javascript you can do `window.open(local_url)` and it will run or open that file/folder. The file can also be a `.bat` file, and you can run anything from it (including Node code).

There are some security considerations for using this though if you're worried other websites might be able to open files in your system. but the extension prompts you every time you try to open something with `localexplorer`

---

If you're still interested on this, a way I use for it to work without the prompt with less risk is this:

The prompt also lets you click the checkbox of `Always open links of this type in the associated app` for each domain. So then what you can do, is have a specific domain you choose for this, to always use that domain to open `localexplorer` links, and use a format of your choosing, like `secretdomain.com/?C:\\path\\to\\file`, and grant access to always open the links on that domain. Then use Tampermonkey to run some code on that domain so that when it detects that specific url format, to redirect the page to a `localexplorer` url, like this
`location.href.replace(/htt.*:\/\/secretdomain.com\/\?/,'localexplorer:')`